# How to change the highlight color of the selected listview item

Tags: vb.net

I tried do this code:

```
Dim hlcolor As Color = SystemColors.Highlight
hlcolor = color.green
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me. This is just an experiment.
Also, is it possible to leave a single column "without a highlight" when

```
fullrowselect = true?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, the hlcolor = color.green is already in the nextline

Comment: say, i put the code in listview1_click event

Comment: What you are doing is wrong buddy. [Refer this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26462109/Change-ListView-Highlight-Color.html)